# Rails ActiveRecord plugin acts_as_versioned for Java (JPA)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jpa, acts-as-versioned

Anyone know of an equivalent of the acts_as_versioned plugin for ActiveRecord in Rails for Java (more specifically for JPA)

I'm asking before I have to go to the trouble of re-modelling to accomodate and rolling my own :o)

Comment: p.s. as far as i understand it, the @Version annotation is mostly used for optimistic locking, so don't know if this can be appropriated...

Comment: Since you're asking a java crowd that likely is unfamiliar with acts_as_versioned, it may be useful for you to explain what it does so we can find you an equivalent technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest equivalent is probably [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers/).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for (even if I accepted ridiculously late)